# Empty ExtJS model instance with 'hasOne' association

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have two ExtJS models linked by 'hasOne' association like so:

```
Ext.define('MyProj.model.Car', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'MyProj.model.CarPassport'
    ],

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'model', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'passportId', type: 'int' }
    ],

    associations: [
        { type: 'hasOne', model: 'CarPassport', primaryKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'passportId', getterName: 'getCarPassport', setterName: 'setCarPassport' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyProj.model.CarPassport', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'color', type: 'string' }
    ],
});
```

Assotiation multiplicity is 1 to 1 - car cannot exist without car passport.
When i'm trying to create empty Car instance, ExtJS doesn't add linked entity to primary entity:

```
var car = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('MyProj.model.Car').create();
car.getCarPassport(); // This string produce error - getCarPassport is undefined
```

So, is it possible to create Car model instance with linked CarPassport model instance, and if true, how?
Thanks...

Comment: hasOne association is only available since extjs 4.1.3, make sure you have the correct sources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found link to this blogpost at Sencha forums and it was helped:

[Client side associations](http://mitchellsimoens.com/2013/03/ext-js-4/client-side-associations/)